# Can I change the file extension of a document that is already in a document library?

Tags: 2007, document, file-upload

So I recently had a nice hitch in the SharePoint app I made for my client. We have a Document Library which is supposed to contain PDFs, converted from drawing files made in other programs. The test system has been deployed for public testing for his clients. This is real site usage, by the way, so real corporate data is being transfered. The site had been tested to be stable on the code side of things, but naturally I failed to take into account user-based errors. The testers uploaded a file in its normal file format instead of converting it to PDF first. And it's already passed through the entire first leg of the approval process before anyone caught this. I plan to implement [this question's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/) in the future to prevent this from happening again, but now I need to fix this current situation.

Because this is a real field test, I cannot simply upload the new PDF file and run it through the process, I need to maintain the field data from the original file, in all of its versions as well. Is there a way I can somehow upload the PDF as a new version of the original file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your site/document library with SharePoint Designer and rename the file from the Designer UI. In my test case versions were preserved.

I initially thought you could do it from Windows Explorer view but it does not allow you to change the extension (on Windows 7).

Comment: Hey, that works perfectly! I uploaded the correct PDF, and then deleted the old version (the new version has all the same data carried over, so it becomes safe to delete the bad file). Thanks a bunch! Now to implement that blocker...