# Editing library doc filenames in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, versioning, library, rename

In order to upload a PDF as the next version of a document that had been a PPTX file and keep versioning intact, I wanted to implement the answer from this question: [Can I change the file extension of a document that is already in a document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/), but I cant figure out how to change the name of a document in a library in SharePoint Designer 2010. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **All files**, navigate to your document library folder, and then right-click on the document, and select **Rename** in the context menu:

[image]

Comment: Omlin - Your breadcrumbs tell me you're in "all files". I can't even see an "all files" in my interface. It's entirely possible I'm noobing this to death, but can you tell me how to navigate to this location in Designer? I'm wondering if the powers-that-obstruct have locked it down...

Comment: Hmm... After you open a site, you should see **All files** in the left panel (Navigation -> Site Objects). Maybe you have it minimized, so you should click there.

Comment: Arg. I don't think anything's minimized. I'm going to post this issue as a separate question, but I have a hunch it's somehow locked down by our SharePoint team who, incidental, don't support our use of Designer...

Comment: Yes, I think you're possibly right. There are some security settings for SharePoint Designer, so lack of "All files" could be due to the permission restrictions.