# Blocking specific file types for a specific document library

Tags: 2007, document-library, file-upload

I know I can block certain types of files from uploading for all document libraries but I was thinking how can I block it for a specific document library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind would be to [create an Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858.aspx) and hook into the ItemAdding() event.  That would let you test the file prior to it being added to the library so that you can reject it if it is not an approved extension.

There is probably a way to do this via Workflow as well but that isn't as clean of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is [the same question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/how-to-restrict-a-document-library-to-a-specific-file-type-extension). As Dave Wise said the simplest way is to use Event Reseiver. You can see [this example](http://salaudeen.blogspot.com/2012/07/allow-only-certain-file-types-to-be.html) to undestand how to use it.