# Document library to support/store/upload .doc,.xls files only

Tags: document, library

I am searching for an OOTB procedure to make Document library support store/upload of a specific type of file (based on extension - for example .doc, .xls).

Can anyone provide specific guidance on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ganesha,

Seems duplicate of following question:
[How to restrict a document library to a specific file type (extension)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/how-to-restrict-a-document-library-to-a-specific-file-type-extension)

Answer from the post:

> there is no OOB solution for this. But you could create an
>   eventhandler (event receiver) and triggers on item adding, that checks
>   the file name and if it's not the correct file extension just cancel
>   event.

Other top answer from the post:

> If you prefer not to deploy any of your own custom code to your WFEs
>   then you may want to consider a simple SharePoint Designer workflow as
>   well.
>
> Have a look at [this
>   article](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/sharepoint-workflow-power-pack-user.html)
>   that describes something similar and can easily be adapted (it renames
>   a file from a workflow when it contains sensitive information in the
>   file name).
>
> Providing feedback to the customer is indeed a problem. An event
>   receiver allows you to provide slightly better feedback than a
>   workflow, but only slightly. SharePoint 2010 allows event receivers to
>   provide better feedback.